# useNavigate() is not working even inside the Router context

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a project using react-router v6, and I am getting an error stating `useNavigate() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component.`
For some background, I have two projects that live in the same repo and get built together. We leverage code splitting and import them as needed, not sure if this matters.

Now, I have a setup that is pretty simple:

**(in the `@dummyInc/components` project)**

Dummy.tsx

```
import React from 'react'

export function Dummy() {
  const navigate = useNavigate()

  return <div> Hello World <button onClick={() => navigate('/someRoute')}> </div>
}
```

Then my code uses it in a different project that is just imported.

**(in the `@dummyInc/site` project)**

App.js

```
import React from 'react'
import Dummy from '@dummyInc/components'

export function App() {
  return <div> <Dummy /> </div>
}
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

import App from './src/App'

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Now I have the above and when I try to render it in the browser, it says the following, but I'm not sure how that's possible, it's being rendered in that context.

```
Error: useNavigate() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component.
```

Am I missing something? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are the two repos built each using their own instance of React? If you declared a simple `Dummy2` component in the same repo as the router does that version of the dummy component work? You may need to list React as a peer dependency in the other repo where the components are built instead of as a regular dependency.

Comment: the other repo had no dependencies at all. If I add Dummy2 to the repo it works fine... I changed the other repo to have
```

  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "16.11.0",
    "react-router-dom": "6.3.0"
  }
```
But still, an error, but it says 

Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _reactRouterDom.useNavigation) is not a function